# Positioning a text

Tags: html, css

Im a beginner in Javascript/Html/Css and I need your help guys ! So Im trying to do a website who actualy look like this. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRtzr.png. The problem is that I don't know how to positioning a text that way with the "justify" and actually my text go everywhere Im not sure how to explain it but you will see it. 
Thank you for everyone who will find me some help !!

```css
header {
 background: white
}

ol {
 margin: 0.4em 0px 0.5em;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type:2;
 float:right;
    height: 125px;    
    top: 40px; right: 40px;  
}


p {
 margin: 0.4em 5px 0.5em;
    line-height: 1em;


}
```

```html
<!--authors: Miguel et Lucass-->
<html>
<head bgcolor=grey>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title> Le Basketball </title>
 <header>
  <h1> <center> Le Basketball </center> </h1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 </header> 
</head>
<p align="center">
<table class="center" style="width:800px">
 <tr style="height:300px">
  <center> <td>
<body bgcolor=DAFFA8>
<nav>
 <font size="+2">
  <center> <ul> <p> <a href="#">Aide</a> | 
                    <a href="#">Accueil</a> | 
                    <a href="#">Vous inscrire</a> | 
                    <a href="#">Coordonnées</a> </p> 
     </font>
    </center>
  </ul>
</nav>
<h1> Qu'est-ce que le Basketball? </h1>
<img src="https://www.sportsnet.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Scrubb.jpg" align='right' high='70%' width='30%'>
<p align="justify"> <font size="3" face="georgia"> Le basket-ball ou basketball, fréquemment désigné en français par son abréviation basket, 
    est un sport collectif opposant deux équipes de cinq joueurs sur un terrain rectangulaire. 
    L'objectif de chaque équipe est de faire passer un ballon au sein d'un arceau de 46 cm de diamètre, 
    fixé à un panneau et placé à 3,05 m du sol : le panier. Chaque panier inscrit rapporte deux points à son équipe, 
    à l'exception des tirs effectués au-delà de la ligne des trois points qui rapportent trois points et des lancers
    francs accordés à la suite d'une faute qui rapportent un point. 
    L'équipe avec le nombre de points le plus important remporte la partie. 
</p>
<p align "right";> <font size="3" face="georgia"> Le basket-ball se pratique exclusivement à la main, et les joueurs peuvent se déplacer balle en main en la dribblant sur
    le sol ou en effectuant deux pas maximum sans dribbler. L'équipe en possession du ballon (les attaquants) tente d'inscrire
    des points en réalisant des tirs, des double-pas ou des dunks tandis que l'équipe en défense essaie de les en empêcher en réalisant
    des interceptions de balle ou des contres. Si le tir échoue, les joueurs des deux équipes tentent d'attraper la balle au rebond.  </font>
</p> 
 <p> <img src="http://rseq.ca/ImageGen.ashx?height=270&image=/media/2060882/bb_m_paquin_alex_mcg_a-19-18_credit_matt_garies.jpg" align="left">   
  <br> <h1 align= "right"> Le 8 principes de base de cette discipline </h1>
  <br> Le dribble est le fait de faire rebondir en permanence la balle au sol avec une main. Pour avancer sur le terrain, le joueur doit impérativement dribbler sous peine d'être sanctionné par un marcher. Afin de garder un bon contrôle de balle, il est recommandé de pousser la balle au sol avec le bout des doigts plutôt qu'avec la paume, et de la faire rebondir légèrement de côté (et non devant soi). Lorsque l'on dribble à proximité d'un défenseur, il est préférable de dribbler avec la main la plus éloignée de l'adversaire afin que celui-ci soit plus loin de la balle. Ceci implique d'être aussi agile de la main gauche que de la main droite. En outre, il faut tant que possible dribbler sans regarder la balle, en utilisant la vision périphérique ou ses sensations pour savoir où elle se trouve
  <p>
  <ol type='2'> 
    <li>Le contrôle &nbsp </li>
    <li>La précision</li>
    <li>La vision</li>
    <li>Le force</li>
    <li>L'agilité</li>
    <li>L'intéligence</li>
    <li>La vitesse</li>
    <li>La concentration</li>
    </ol>
</p>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. Which text *specifically* needs to be positioned? What have you tried? Reduce your question and your sample to one specific question. Tnx.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and put it in the question itself instead.

Comment: Hey welcome to SO! There's actually multiple things being done incorrectly here but I'm curious if this is a homework assignment you're looking for someone to help you get an A on or if you're generally looking to learn from example?

Comment: Everything since this line : <br> <h1 align= "right"> Le 8 principes de base de cette discipline </h1 also all the <ol> and the " <p> Le dribble ... " If you look the screenshot you can see that they are not exactly the same. Hope you understand what Im talk about because I am french and new with HTML. And yes it is a project for my class (for tomorow and im stock with that since Tuesday ) Thank you !!!